# Change field name and boolean value to opposite value in the same time

Tags: mongodb, rename, aggregation

i want to create a script for mongoDB and i have property "Active" and i want to change the name of that property to "Deleted" and value where it's "true" to "false" and where it's "false" to "true". If "Active" field its not present in that document then i want to set "Deleted" as "False"

Thanks!

Comment: I know how to change name, i can use $rename for that but i don't know how to change value as well in the same time and how to change values with opposite values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `$set` and `$unset`. Logically `$rename` perform the same.

`db.collection({active: true}, {$unset: {$active: ''}, $set: {$deleted: true}}`

Comment: Thanks man, yes it's working like this, but if someone will have another idea maybe we can learn some new ways how to use mongo better. But thanks for your help for me this was working .